# SPFX React Webpart - Problem with react boostrap

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, boot-strap, react-webpart

I am building my first spfx react webpart to be depoyed on SharePoint Online.
I have trouble making react bootstrap work.

What i want to achieve is to open a form in a modal when the user click on a button.
I am using react bootstrap to create a form and display it in a modal :

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

I include react bootsrap components this way in my component after installing the npm package :

```
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

react bootstrap needs bootstrap to be included for the styling to work.
I first included bootrap css this way in the component tsx file :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

All work fine and it is displayed properly but it has side effects on the Sharepoint UI, for example on other native sharepoint webparts.

So i used sass as described in this post to prevent leaking css:
[SPFX web part, CSS is leaking into the whole sharepoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273405/spfx-web-part-css-is-leaking-into-the-whole-sharepoint-site)

Here is my custom scss file :

```
.my-app {
    @import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
     }
```

I import my custom .scss file this way in the component :

```
import "./bootsrap-custom.scss";
```

The button is rendered properly with the css class .my-app.
But now that i use sass the Modal and the Form are rendered without any style. The modal is displayed without styling at the bottom of the page.

If i put the Form outside of the modal the bootstrap css is applied properly to the Form.

I don't understand why when using sass this way the Modal and every element in this Modal are not rendered properly.